# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource Exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-2

I am very new to both Spring and maven. I am getting an error. I am using Maven from command line to build the project.

I have updated spring-core and spring-context dependencies, after that I have done `mvn clean install` and it says no problem. I did `mvn eclipse:eclipse` after it and it also went fine. I compile with `mvn clean compile` and that passes too. I have checked in .m2 folder ( on MacOS) that yes spring-core is there. Yet while running my project, this run time exception is coming; I have tried several other solutions given on Stack Overflow but none of them worked.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.Resource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

This is my POM file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Spring_1</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringCIList</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>SpringCIList</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



   <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

One quick doubt from my side, could this ( beans -2.5 xsd)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
```

be the problem-root??

Edit 1 Exact run command which is causing exception to occur

```
.

Rishis-MBP:SpringCIList rishiprakash$ cd target/classes/
Rishis-MBP:classes rishiprakash$ ls
Spring_1        spring-module.xml
Rishis-MBP:classes rishiprakash$ java Spring_1.App
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)......
```

App.java

```
package Spring_1;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class App
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

Resource r = new ClassPathResource("spring-module.xml");
BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(r);
Employee e = (Employee)factory.getBean("emp");
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        e.displayInfo();



    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
package Spring_1;

class Employee{

private  String name;

String getName(){
return this.name;
}
void setName(String name){
this.name = name;
}

void displayInfo(){
  System.out.println("name of employee is"+this.name);
}


}
```

spring-module.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="emp" class="Spring_1.Employee">
<property name="name" value="Rishi"></property>
</bean>


  </beans>
```

Same project when imported to eclipse (with m2e plugin) is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run whole application using only .class file and forgetting to tell JVM about dependencies.

Following issue can be solved using: `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="Spring_1.App"`

However I strongly recommend to build jar file or execute it from your IDE (Eclipse, Idea)

Comment: awesome man!!! Thanks a ton :) ; Quick question why it is recommended to run jar with IDE and why java -jar your_app_name.jar does not work?

Comment: IDE helps you with all the boilerplate, java -jar does not work because of the same reason as running java .class -> it's jar without external dependencies. If you still needed I would recommend to check how to build fat jars

Comment: fat jars!! that name ringed a bell in my mind :D Thank you for all the help :) may you have a great day today.

Answer (score 1):

I think that by running your app in that way the classpath does not contain all the dependencies.

Try the following:

1. Build the project by using: `mvn clean package` (this should create a jar file in your target/ folder)
2. Run your app with: `jara -jar your_app_name.jar`

Comment: jara is java (assuming this); also tried with it yet the same error. The other answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

Release is spring-web will work only after version 4.2 of spring.core